# Integrate Admob in iOS App which uses monogame

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, admob, monogame

I am trying to do this for a few days, and still cannot make it. And I tried to find some samples but they are all on Android. Did anyone succeed to integrate admob on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems with [AdMob bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAdMobAds) from monotouch-bindings repository. But then I switched to [AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds) bindings and them works just great. You can find sample of using AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds in README on Github. Is is quite simple, but if you'll need some help - feel free to ask more detailed question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I made it with AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds, i will paste my code here later.

Comment: Everything works well until I click on one AD that links to some website not appstore, the banner just rotate and disappear, nothing shows. Have you ever encounter this? i am working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // code for admob "using AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds"
        UIViewController vc = new UIViewController ();
        UIViewController controller = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows [0].RootViewController;

        var ad = new GADBannerView (GADAdSizeCons.SmartBannerLandscape, new PointF (0, 0))
        {
            AdUnitID = "ADMOB_ID",
            RootViewController = vc
        };
        ad.Hidden = false;

        ad.DidReceiveAd += delegate {
            ad.Hidden = false;
            ad.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (0, (int) 0, (int) (ad.Bounds.Width), (int) (ad.Bounds.Height));
            Console.WriteLine ("AD Received");
        };

        ad.DidFailToReceiveAdWithError += delegate(object sender, GADBannerViewDidFailWithErrorEventArgs e) {
            ad.Hidden = true;
            Console.WriteLine (e.Error);

        };

        ad.WillPresentScreen += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine ("showing new screen");
        };

        ad.WillLeaveApplication += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine ("I will leave application");
        };

        ad.WillDismissScreen += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine ("Dismissing opened screen");
        };
        ad.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        vc.View.AddSubview(ad);
        vc.View.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0f,  0f,  (int)(ad.Bounds.Width), (int)(ad.Bounds.Height));
        controller.View.AddSubview(vc.View);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Requesting Ad");
                InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
                    GADRequest r = new GADRequest();

                    ad.LoadRequest(r);
                });
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }
        });
```